How to create a monorepo with 2 expo projects and an express
I have 3 projects:
office/ <--expo
patient/ <--expo
backend/ <--express
I want to share dependencies between all 3 projects (such as moment.js), but also share dependencies between just office and patient (such as react-native, expo, etc...).
Maybe something like this:
apps/
    backend/
        package.json // backend specific dependencies
    expo/
        package.json // dependencies shared by office and patient, not by backend
        office/
            package.json // office specific dependencies
        patient/
            package.json // patient specific dependencies
package.json // dependencies shared by office patient and backend

Is this possible?

Take a look at this expo tutorial.
It uses yarn workspaces to work and helps you set it up
